# Sql Server retrieve last date for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns `Emp`, `Surname`, `CSD`, `Term Rsn` and `Date`. The first 4 columns will stay the same but the date will change eg. There can be 30 records for an Emp with 30 different dates.

This is my code which works but when I add [Date] to the select it returns all 30 records whereas i am trying to return one record with the last date

```
Create  PROCEDURE testPro(    
@reportStartDate date,
@reportEndDate date    
)    
AS
BEGIN    


SELECT DISTINCT Emp, Surname, CSD, CASE WHEN CSD<= @reportStartDate
THEN 

CASE WHEN [Term Rsn] != 0 THEN
CASE WHEN [Date] <= @reportEndDate THEN
(DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, [Date]) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,[Date])))+1 ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 END  ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 END


ELSE 

CASE WHEN [Term Rsn] != 0 THEN 
CASE WHEN [Date] <= @reportEndDate THEN
(DATEDIFF(dd,CSD, [Date]) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,CSD,[Date])))+1 ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,CSD, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,CSD,@reportEndDate)))+1 END ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,CSD, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,CSD,@reportEndDate)))+1 END 

END AS [Working Days]

FROM GyPremiumsTemp
WHERE CSD < @reportEndDate AND [Date] >  @reportStartDate --AND [Date] = (select max([Date]) FROM GyPremiumsTemp)
ORDER BY Emp ASC
END


    EXEC  testPro '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'
```

Comment: Add Where condition (emp id) in Subquery and try it.

Comment: Have you considered **normalising** your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as below:

```
Create  PROCEDURE testPro(    
@reportStartDate date,
@reportEndDate date    
)    
AS
BEGIN  
select Emp, Surname, CSD,[Working Days] , Max(Date) as [Date]
From (
SELECT DISTINCT Emp, Surname, CSD, CASE WHEN CSD<= @reportStartDate
THEN 

CASE WHEN [Term Rsn] != 0 THEN
CASE WHEN [Date] <= @reportEndDate THEN
(DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, [Date]) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,[Date])))+1 
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 END  
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 END


ELSE 

CASE WHEN [Term Rsn] != 0 THEN 
CASE WHEN [Date] <= @reportEndDate THEN
(DATEDIFF(dd,CSD, [Date]) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,CSD,[Date])))+1 
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,CSD, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,CSD,@reportEndDate)))+1 END 
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,CSD, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,CSD,@reportEndDate)))+1 END 

END AS [Working Days],[Date] -- Add all Dates here

FROM GyPremiumsTemp
WHERE CSD < @reportEndDate AND [Date] >  @reportStartDate
) T
Group By Emp, Surname, CSD,[Working Days] 
ORDER BY Emp ASC
END


EXEC  testPro '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/PHN78705) Here.

Comment: If i don't want to print the date if the Term Rsn is not null, what would i add?

Comment: I didn't get you .. in both the case statement above you have added case condition for [Term Rsn] != 0 only..

Comment: Ya sorry, both of them are used to determine which dates to use. For the Term Rsn if it isn't 0 then i would like to print the date and if it is 0 then i want to print "NULL" or something else for the date

Comment: In that case when [Term Rsn] = 0 you can add a dummy date say '01-01-1900' or '01-01-1800' whatever that might not be an feasible value for date column in the inner query and in outer query you can add a case filter as: * Case when MAx(Date) ='01-01-1800' then '' else Max(Date) end as [Date].*

Answer (score 1):

When selecting Date field use:
   Select max(Date),Emp,Surname
from table 
group by Emp,Surname

```
This will give you one record per employee.I hope this helps.
```